# How do I move to a new world and keep my stuff?

Tags: terraria

In the [Terraria 1.0.5 changelog](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/33191/), I read that parts of the world generation algorithm have been changed.

So, I would like to create a new world and move my character there, but how can I easily transfer all my old things (mainly chest contents) to the new world?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both your character's inventory and the contents of your piggy-bank and safe transfer across worlds.

So, go to the old world, fill up your inventory and piggy bank/safe, move to the new world, dump it all in chests, rinse and repeat!

Comment: Do you need to rebuy the piggy bank on the new world, however?

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck The piggy bank is also an item that you can carry in your inventory.

Comment: It took a lot of time to move all my things, I hope they will implement a new feature or a bigger inventory, in the meanwhile this is the correct answer.

Comment: With the dungeon defenders cross over, the [defender's forge](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Defender%27s_Forge) is added which functions like safe except it requires more space to be placed

Answer (score 6):

To add to BlueRaja's answer, you can also buy a [Safe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Safe) when you get some money (it costs 50 gold). It acts almost like a piggy bank, but makes it easier to travel between the worlds:

- Each Safe contains the same items (when accessed by the same
  character), no matter where they are placed within the world.
  Purchasing multiple Safes will not give you more space, but will
  offer more points of access to your Safe contents.
- The Safe can be picked up even when it contains items. This makes it
  a viable way to expand your character's inventory slots. It can be
  removed with a Hammer to be picked up again.
- The Safe's contents are saved with your character data, instead of
  the World data. You keep its contents with you from world to world,
  and from server to server.
- The Safe's contents are exclusive to each player, so other players
  will not have access to items in your Safe. This makes it useful for
  item security on PvP servers where stealing is allowed.
- Multiple players can use the same Safes without having access to each
  others items. Each player will only see their own items when
  accessing the same Safes.

Comment: How exactly does the safe make transferring between worlds easier than the piggy bank does? According to the wiki the _only_ differences between the two are the cost and what surfaces they can be placed on.

Comment: If nothing else, it gives you 20 extra (expensive) slots so you make less turns between worlds (in case you have both)